# How to detect image edges with different contrast and background color using Opencv?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, android

I'm developing an Android application to detect all image contours and draw them using Opencv.

I was testing on the same image and everything was working fine.

But as soon as I changed the same image but with different contrast the detection fails.

Also I changed another sample image with darker background and it fails again.

Here is the code:

```
  Imgproc.cvtColor(mRGBA, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

    Core.split(mGray, channels);

    mGray = channels.get(1);

    Imgproc.threshold(mGray, mGray, 50, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

    Core.meanStdDev(mGray, mu, stddev);

    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mGray, mGray, new Size(5, 5), 5);

    //Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mGray, 20, 80, 3, false);

    Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mGray, mu.get(0, 0)[0], stddev.get(0, 0)[0], 3, false);

    Mat kernell = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(9,9));

    Imgproc.morphologyEx(mGray, mGray, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, kernell);

    Imgproc.dilate(mGray, mGray, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_CROSS, new Size(3, 3)));
```

Here is the first sample image

[image]

Processing result

[image]

Here is a second sample image

[image]

And here is the result

[image]

I must point to the fact that if I remove the image thresholding, the algorithm works perfectly for the same image in different light intensity and different contrast but only works on images with white background.

Is there a way to apply Canny in a generic way?

Comment: You use `threshold` with a fixed threshold of `50`. Try using the `THRESH_OTSU` option (see the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57)). Alternatively, you could try `adaptiveThreshold` ([doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3)). Also, is this `Imgproc.cvtColor(mRGBA, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);` intended? Your variable is named `mGray`, but you convert to HSV!?

Comment: I will try THRESH_OTSU instead and give you the update, variable is named mGray because I was converting the image to gray and it didn't work well with image shadow so I converted the image to HSV and used the saturation channel for better results. Write a complete answer and I will accept if it works fine. Thank you anyway Sir.

Comment: @HansHirse `THRESH_OTSU ` didn't work out, same results. Also  `adaptiveThreshold` didn't give me good results. What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to have better results for all types of images by using **CLAHE** technique from Opencv to enhance image contrast with a clip limit of 1.

Of course clip limit variable is application dependant and 1 worked almost perfectly for me.

And I removed the image thresholding.

Here is what I've added just before applying **GaussianBlur** :

```
    CLAHE clahe = Imgproc.createCLAHE();

    clahe.setClipLimit(1);

    clahe.apply(mGray, mGray);
```